# VB.Net - How do you "dynamically" select an object?

Tags: vb.net, object

I'm not sure if the question properly asks what I want, because I'm a bit new, but what I am trying to do is write a sub or function that I can run when a label is clicked, and I want to to be reusable on multiple labels. There will be 12 in total, and I don't wish to write the same thing over and over, with slightly different characters. A programmer never wants to write the same thing twice, right?  Also, something else is making it a necessity to do it dynamically.

So, how I was trying to accomplish that was by using a string, and adding the name of the label to the string on click.

```
 click1 = "Label1"
```

As it turns out, you can't just say click1.Text and return the text of Label1. The reason it's important to do it implicitly is because I need to somehow remember the one I clicked before, to compare the first click and second click, and if they match, do A, and if they don't match, do B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first parameter (it is called sender) to the event handler your wrote to respond to the click event is the object which sent the event.

If you assign the same routine to respond to on click of all your labels, it will be called for every one of them, but the sender parameter will point to the actual label which was clicked

HTH

Comment: Thank you!  Kind of confusing, but I learned something from it, so still quite useful!

Answer (score 1):

mfeingold is correct, if you're unsure of the syntax:

```
Private Sub LabelClicked (ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click, Label2.Click, Label3.Click
    sender.Text = "I've been clicked."
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the syntax. I hadn't seen it before.

Comment: +1 you can also wire the events in the form designer. Select all the labels, go to properties window, event tab, find the Click event and use the dropdown to select the routine that will handle all the events. Or type a new name & it will create routine for you.